# Can't see Dialog Fragment in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, dialog, fragment, dialogfragment

I use dialog fragment to show dialog from activity.
There is no error and I can find Log at my Logcat but I can't see the dialog when I run the application.
I don't know what's the problem.

Here is my Activity code:

```
btnEventRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                DialogPlusEvent dialogPlusEvent = new DialogPlusEvent();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("eventPlaceName", eventPlaceName);
                bundle.putLong("currentUserDistance", currentUserDistance);

                dialogPlusEvent.setArguments(bundle);

                dialogPlusEvent.show(fragmentManager, "DialogPlusEvent");
                Log.d("Dialog Fragment", "Working");
            }
        });
```

Dialog Fragment code:

```
public class DialogPlusEvent extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView dpeTvPlaceName, dpeStar, dpeTvMyDistance;
    private String dpePlaceName;
    private Long dpeMyDistance;
    private Button dpeBtnOkay;


    public static DialogPlusEvent getInstance() {
        DialogPlusEvent dialogPlusEvent = new DialogPlusEvent();

        return  dialogPlusEvent;
    }

    @Nullable
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_plus_event, container);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentPage = sharedPreferences.getString("currentPage", "");
        
        /.../


        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        dpePlaceName = bundle.getString("eventPlaceName");
        dpeMyDistance = bundle.getLong("currentUserDistance");


        dpeBtnOkay = view.findViewById(R.id.dpeBtnOkay);
        dpeBtnOkay.setOnClickListener(this);
        setCancelable(false);

        return  view;
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake while implementing the `onCreateView` method

Just change the method from `OnCreateView` to `onCreateView` like below :

```
 @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_plus_event, container);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentPage = sharedPreferences.getString("currentPage", "");
        
        /.../


        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        dpePlaceName = bundle.getString("eventPlaceName");
        dpeMyDistance = bundle.getLong("currentUserDistance");


        dpeBtnOkay = view.findViewById(R.id.dpeBtnOkay);
        dpeBtnOkay.setOnClickListener(this);
        setCancelable(false);

        return  view;
    }
```

Comment: @SoyoungKim please check if the `onCreateView` is called

Comment: How can I check that..? Can I check that with log? Sorry for asking.. I'm super beginner of programming..

Comment: I checked it. And I think `onCreateView` is not called. I can find the log which is at Activity but there is no DialogFragment log.

Comment: do you have any warning in the DialogFragment like "this method is never used" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231488/discussion-between-shay-kin-and-soyoung-kim).

Answer (score 0):

@Shay Kin is right.  you did not implement the onCreateView method correctly.

I ran the code as you provided, it works well and I can see the dialog, so I think the problem is not in this code.

```
public class TestFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_fragment);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_click).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        DialogPlusEvent dialogPlusEvent = new DialogPlusEvent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        dialogPlusEvent.setArguments(bundle);

        dialogPlusEvent.show(fragmentManager, "DialogPlusEvent");
        Log.d("Dialog Fragment", "Working");
    }
}
```

```
public class DialogPlusEvent extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView dpeTvPlaceName, dpeStar, dpeTvMyDistance;
    private String dpePlaceName;
    private Long dpeMyDistance;
    private Button dpeBtnOkay;


    public static DialogPlusEvent getInstance() {
        DialogPlusEvent dialogPlusEvent = new DialogPlusEvent();

        return  dialogPlusEvent;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_plus_event, container);
        setCancelable(false);

        return  view;
    }



    public void onClick(View view) {
        dismiss();
    }
}
```